# Query for Simple Survey Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm building a simple survey with tables 'survey', 'surveyquestions', and 'surveyanswers'. I'm having the toughest time wrapping my mind around how to grab a specific question and a specific answer from the output (without using foreach, given the random order of the questions in the view) and populate my views. I'm using Laravel 4.1.  Below is my query.

Does anybody have any suggestions about how I can retrieve, for example, question 1 and answer 1 in my view? Thanks in advance.

I'm using Laravel 4.1.

QUERY

```
$survey = Survey::survey(1)
    ->with(array(
    'questions' => function($query)
    {
        $query->where('survey_id', '=', '1');
    },
    'questions.answers' => function($query)
    {   
        $query->where('project_id', '=', '1080');
    }))
    ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Here's how I found the answer for a question in case it helps somebody down the road:

```php
$answer = $survey->find(1)->answers()->select('answer')->where('question_id', '=', 1)->first('answer');
```

EDIT:

This is a better solution since it queries the collection set without hitting the database

```php
$answer = $survey->questions->find($questionId)->answers->first()->answer
```